# SQL CTE recursive with multiple iterations

Tags: sql, mariadb, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have issues understanding CTE recursive. Let's say I want to calculate binomial coefficient. My guess is I need two CTEs as I want to have one that generates table with all values in some range (for example to get (4,2) I need to have (3,2)  and (3,1) and so on) and the second one that kind of sums everything? I'm lost - I need to iterate not only on n but also on k. And it would be nice if I started with (0,0) and then (1,0) (calculated using previous calculations), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1).
The thing is I have no idea how to do that. I tried making two CTEs but I can't get the idea of how to iterate both of them. Is there a trick to do that?
Also, I was thinking - maybe start with (n,0) and then (n,1), (n,2)... but to do that I also need other binomial coefficients.
I'm using Mariadb, if this is relevent here.

EDIT:
Here's something I wrote (obviously it doesn't work, I wanted to fiddle with recursion).

```
WITH RECURSIVE
kiterate (n, k, res) AS
(
SELECT 0, 0, 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT n, k+1, 0 -- there should be result 
FROM kiterate WHERE n < k
)
SELECT * FROM kiterate;
```

But I want to obtain something like that. I have n, I have k, now what I need to do is to generate the result. To do that I need to calculate almost everything till I reach (0,0) (or maybe it's not necessary?). The thing that I don;t understand is how to iterate on n and k. As mentioned above if I want to calculate (4,2) I need (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) (not sure if all of this but I hope you get the idea). So I have to change n and k. But not at the same time. Something like if statement would be great but I'm pretty sure it's not the case here.

Comment: I don't really see a question here.  Do you have sample data and desired results?

Comment: Well, I want to calculate, for instance, binomial coefficient (5,3). So what I want to get is the result of that. I started writing CTE but it seems I'm missing something. I'm going to edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to compute a binomial coefficient in SQL. The typical formula for `C(n, k)` is `n! / k! / (n - k)!`.

In SQL, one approach uses one recursive CTE for each factorial, like so:

```
with recursive 
    params as (select 4 n, 2 k),
    r1 as (
        select n, n res from params
        union all select n - 1, res * (n - 1) from r1 where n > 1
    ),
    r2 as (
        select k, k res from params
        union all select k - 1, res * (k - 1) from r2 where k > 1
    ),
    r3 as (
        select (n - k) m, (n - k) res from params 
        union all select m - 1, res * (m - 1) from r3 where m > 1
    )
select max(r1.res) / max(r2.res) / max(r3.res) 
from r1
cross join r2
cross join r3
```

The `params` CTE gives the parameters for the computation - here, `C(4, 2)`. Then each of the three CTEs computes one factorial, and the outer query does the final computation.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d14c02191a2e2ee6ed5da5c2cd83454)**: `C(4, 2)` is `6`.

Comment: Thank you, I will analyze this code. But what if I really want to use the recursive definition?

Comment: @Awerde: your question mentions that you want to compute the binomial coefficient, so that's what the query does. If you want the  list of combinations, then that's a rather different question.

Comment: @GMB I think what he wants is not through direct formula but through recursive formula for example :   C(n, k) = C(n-1, k-1) + C(n-1, k) until we reach one of these conditions :   C(n, 0) = C(n, n) = 1 .