# Get combination over two columns

Tags: sql

Help me to get SQL

| column 1 | column 2 | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DEP-1 | 1 | 1 |
| DEP-1 | 1 | 2 |
| DEP-1 | 2 | 3 |
| DEP-2 | 3 | 4 |
| DEP-3 | 1 | 5 |
| DEP-3 | 2 | 6 |
| DEP-3 | 3 | 7 |
| DEP-3 | 2 | 8 |
| DEP-3 | 3 | 9 |

I have above table I need to write SQL to display all DISTINCT combination of column 2 over column 1. for example DEP-1 has 1 and 2 in column 2. my final table has to look below.

| column 1 | column 2 | Id | column 2 map |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEP-1 | 1 | 1 | 1~2 |
| DEP-1 | 1 | 2 | 1~2 |
| DEP-1 | 2 | 3 | 1~2 |
| DEP-2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| DEP-3 | 1 | 5 | 1~2~3 |
| DEP-3 | 2 | 6 | 1~2~3 |
| DEP-3 | 3 | 7 | 1~2~3 |
| DEP-3 | 2 | 8 | 1~2~3 |
| DEP-3 | 3 | 9 | 1~2~3 |

Comment: Check [binomial coefficents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688023/sql-cte-recursive-with-multiple-iterations) with CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select origin.*, c2_map
from origin
join (
 select c1, group_concat("~", c2) as c2_map
 from (
   select distinct c1, c2 from origin
 ) t1
 group by c1
) t2
on origin.c1 = t2.c1
```

Note:

- `group_concat(sep, value)` is an aggregate function, it depends on the database you use, it means join the values together using sep